# Refer to another field value to affect a new one in MySQL w/Node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, backend

thanks for reading.
I have a table with 3 fields, one is the ID, which autoincrements and I can´t access it from my Node.js server since it's added by MySql. Another field contains a string, and the last field should be the sum of the 3 first letters of the string field, added to the id.
The thing is, when I do my query I can't just add them up because the id doesn´t exist until the query is sent to the DB.
What should I do? It'd be such an inconvenience to handle the ID autoincrement from the API.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why do you need the third column, if it's always determined by the other two columns? Couldn't you use a virtual column for it?

Answer (score 0):

After you insert the row, you can get its ID and update the third column.

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO yourTable (name) VALUES (?)', [name], function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  let code = name.substr(0, 3) + result.insertId;
  connection.query('UPDATE yourTable SET code = ? WHERE id = ?', [code, result.insertId], function(err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
});
```

However, this won't work if you're inserting multiple rows in bulk, since `result.insertId` is just the last row that was inserted.

You could update all the rows where the code

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO yourTable (name) VALUES ?', names.map(n => [n]), function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  connection.query('UPDATE yourTable SET code = CONCAT(SUBSTR(name, 1, 3), id) WHERE code IS NULL', function(err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  });
});
```